# jQuery not catching right clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to distinguish left and right click using jQuery like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    alert(e.which);
});
```

On left click I get the desired alert but on right click I get nothing. How can I fix it?

See http://jsfiddle.net/399Hf/.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [contextmenu event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/contextmenu)

```
$('#container').on('click contextmenu', '.item', function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9ucbU/)

Comment: Great! Now how to do the same for middle click as well? :-)

Comment: in that case look at `mousedown` event as given in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Use mouse down event like this:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true;    });
```

In this solution you can verify every mouse button just by changing the condition in the if instructon.

```
if( e.button == 3 ) { 
          alert('Third mouse button!'); 
          return false; 
        }
```

etc.

Comment: IMO, i'd use mouseup event instead. Anyway +1